# Why is Drupal 7 loading the wrong .js file?

Tags: 7, caching, proxies

There is a very strange bug that is happening on one of our client websites, and we have been unable to figure out what's going on. It's a tough one.

**The Issue**

---

In simple terms, Drupal is loading the wrong JavaScript file. We have a custom theme for the site. In the theme's .info file there is this line:

`scripts[] = script/script.js`

A couple of weeks ago we updated the .info file. The original .info file contained:

`scripts[] = script/script-min.js`

The script and script-min files are completely different files, and the server should be loading the `script.js` file.

Here is the behavior we are witnessing:

- When we flush theme cache, Drupal reads in the .info file and loads `script.js`
- After cron runs (every 5 minutes) Drupal will randomally decide to load `script-min.js`
- If we check the database, the `system` table shows that Drupal has cached `script-min.js`

*It should be noted that nothing in the code is loading script-min.js. We have grepped through and cannot find where Drupal would even be trying to load the file from. The script-min.js file exists in the script directory along-side the script.js file, but nowhere is it referenced.*

**Our Setup**

---

- Acquia Cloud Hosting w/ Git and PHP 5.3+
- 3 environments (dev, stage, production)
- Production environment has two web servers, a balancer, varnish and MySQL. Web servers use Gluster file system to sync files
- This issue does not appear to show up on our dev/stage servers

**What we've tried**

---

None of these fixes worked:

- Rebuilding registry
- Removing script-min.js file
- Targeting web server IPs to rule out an issue with the dual-server setup
- Clearing all caches
- Clearing Varnish cache

**Why we need help**

---

We have been trying to diagnose this issue for nearly two weeks now, and we've run out of the obvious ideas. Our main theory right now is that their might be an issue with the two web servers, but from all of our testing, it doesn't appear to be the case... But does make the most sense.

We are aware that we could probably get the server to use the right JS file by just using `drupal_add_js` instead of the .info method, but we really want to know *why* the server is loading a file that we are not telling it to.

**EDITS**

---

These modules implement hook_cron() on the site:
acquia_agent,
acquia_spi,
ctools,
dblog,
field,
googleanalytics,
node,
scheduler,
system,
update,
xmlsitemap_node,
xmlsitemap,
xmlsitemap_engines

I have already checked, and during cron, the `drupal_clear_js_cache`, `system_rebuild_theme_data`, and `drupal_theme_rebuild` functions are **not** hit. My original assumptions had to do with those functions, but if they are not running during cron, they are probably not the issue.

We think the issue might be related to this bug report: http://drupal.org/node/1765812

Comment: after cron run is only `script-min.js` loaded or both scripts?

Comment: After cron, Drupal loads only the `script-min.js` file. And I should mention that the server seems like it is loading an old .info file, as it is not loading another javascript file that was added to the new .info file. The weird part, is there is NO old .info file on the server, at all...

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your GlusterFS.

Comment: We thought it might be a GFS issue, but we don't know too much about it, or what might be going on. We've run tests to make sure the files are syncing between the two servers and they are syncing very quickly.

Comment: Assuming that it is an issue with the application, I'd probably check for implementations of `hook_system_info_alter()`, `hook_js_alter()` in enabled custom & contrib modules & themes. One of them could be inadvertantly doing this.

Comment: Thank you @AmarnathRavikumar I will look into this. Still not sure how it would load old information though.

Comment: @AmarnathRavikumar - Checked out all the implementations of those hooks, and nothing seems to be the trouble maker.

Comment: are you sure it's Drupal?  can you include more information about the production server? is it Apache? any non-standard mods?  I wonder if the server is rewriting or redirecting to -min.js because it sees the file is available...

Comment: We need more info in order to solve this issue. Lets see what modules have cron hooks. `<?php foreach (module_implements('cron') as $module) { echo $module . "<br>\n"; } ?>`. Report back here what that list is.

Comment: I am not sure the problem is Drupal, it could be some other configuration. However, the `script-min.js` string does not even exist on the server.

Comment: @donutdan4114 did you look for "min.js"?  I'm totally guessing here, but I know that some servers can be set up to automatically use minified js files if they're there.

Comment: We did look for anything mentioning "min.js". We didn't find anything related to the script-min.js issue though...

Comment: Added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with a rogue server that was hitting our site. The old web server was hitting our database and caching the old files.

It was hard to find because the two servers had the same hostname for some reason.